# Github: accidentally push git without commit

Tags: android, git, github, push

I just started to use `Github` and made a stupid mistake. 
I was working on a `branch` named 'entry' and trying to `commit` and `push` current works to new `branch` 'entry2'. However, as soon as I made 'entry2' with:

```
git branch entry2
git checkout entry2
```

and accidentally pushed it without adding or committing.

```
git push origin entry2
```

Now I have data that `committed` a few days ago and all my works saved in the `repo` is gone. I searched about restoring methods but I'm afraid to try because I haven't done any of adding and committing steps. What can I do to recover my files? By the way, I'm making an app with the **Android Studio**. Is there any possibility that Android Studio holds the previous version of my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can find `local history` of any file in `Android Studio` as follows -

Right Click File in `Android Studio` from `Project View` -> Select **local History** -> Select **Show History**. This will show all the changes made to that file recently along with time.

2) According to the steps you have done with `git`, your local changes should be present in `entry2 branch`.

When you did `checkout` from `entry1 branch` to `entry2 branch`, your local (uncommitted) changes moved to `entry2`.

When you pushed your `branch entry2` to `origin`, your local data remained there because always commits are pushed to origin. In your case, since this was new `branch`, the `entry2 branch` was pushed to `origin` without any commits. Your local data is not pushed, nor lost. It is still there at `entry2 branch`. You can check that by doing -

```
git status
```

3) In case you already `commited` your data on `entry1 branch` before checkout to `entry2 branch`, your data must be present at `entry1 branch`. You can `checkout` to entry1 to get back your data.

**Note:** I am assuming that you did exactly what you have told in question. If yes, the above should work. However, you can always get back your `local changes` from `Android Studio`.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already done a commit at one branch and just checked out to another, you can checkout to your first branch using 
`git checkout entry`
and push commits using `git push -u origin entry`